# How to make a toggle switch between two font families

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make simple toggle switch between to font families. Idea is to allow users to change two fonts. Currently, my code looks like this:

**JS**

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("body")
    if (x.style.fontFamily = "OpenDyslexic") {
        x.style.fontFamily = "OpenDyslexic";
    } else {
        x.style.fontFamily = "Noto";
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">
   <span class=" slider round"></span>
</label>
```

My code change font to “***OpenDyslexic***” but I can’t change to ***Noto*** font, toggle not working. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: First you forgot to use "==" for comparison. Second you are comparing and assigning same values, reverse them.

Answer (score 0):

You just missed the if equals

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("body")
    if (x.style.fontFamily == "OpenDyslexic") {
        x.style.fontFamily = "OpenDyslexic";
    } else {
        x.style.fontFamily = "Noto";
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

To toggle this you need to try something like this :

```
function myFunction() {

    const x = document.getElementById("body");

    x.style.fontFamily = x.style.fontFamily == "Noto" ? "OpenDyslexic" : "Noto";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that:

```
const myFunction = () => {
    const x = document.getElementById('body');
    x.style.fontFamily = x.style.fontFamily == 'Noto' ? 'OpenDyslexic' : 'Noto';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You've an issue on your if statement. 
You're using a single `=` that is used for variable assignment. For that reason is always setting the font family to "OpenDyslexic". 
I suggest you to use the strict equality comparison: `===`

The code without errors should be:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("body")
    if (x.style.fontFamily === "OpenDyslexic") {
        x.style.fontFamily = "OpenDyslexic";
    } else {
        x.style.fontFamily = "Noto";
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues in your code:

1. You are using assignment operator (`=`) where you should use the comparison operator (`==` or `===`), hence the condition always evaluates to `true`.
2. You are setting the same value for the property if the condition is `true` which is logically incorrect.

**Demo:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("body");
  if (x.style.fontFamily == "Verdana") {
    x.style.fontFamily = "Arial";
  } else {
    x.style.fontFamily = "Verdana";
  }
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
<label>Some Text</label>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">
   <span class=" slider round"></span>
</label>
</body>
```